# CSS media queries and !important

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a website of which uses @media queries but it doesn't seem to set them. They always keep the default style.

For example:

```
#div1 { background:red}

@media screen and (max-height:912px) {
#div1{background:blue}
}
```

will always stick with **background:red** unless I use `!important` but within my media queries I am styling so many selectors. Do I need to set to every single selector style `!important` ?

Comment: Your code is working fine on my system. I have tested in to Firefox, chrome and safari on Mac. What is your testing environment?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was trying to figure why it is not working. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/3/ Try to make the color blue by resizing. It never happens

Comment: It will only choose the color of which is last in the css section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change max-height to min-height: http://jsfiddle.net/jnQYb/

Comment: Link is not working anymore.

Comment: Is there any explanation for why this works (if it works, jsfiddle doesn't work)?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. I realized that media queries have to be at the end of style sheets (even if you're using/importing multiple files on your workflow).

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me.

Take a look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/1/ - the background is red, but when you change the result part height it changes to blue on some point.

What browser are you trying on?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was trying to figure why it is not working. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/3/ Try to make the color blue by resizing. It never happens

Comment: Thats right, but it's proper behavior, because `background: green` overrides `background: blue`. You should write something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/5/ to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, **!important** is used to override the default css i.e. to override attributes used in the default style. So, if there is a new attribute in the media queries, u do not have to use it along with that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example in //jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/55/:
You need to change the order of the media queries. 
    max-height:510px;
includes 
    max-height:500px;
it has to come first in order for the more special case of 500px beeing displayed at all.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/TUL6h/55 wouldn't be mine. Mine was created up to 5. The rest are from users around here.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of !important inside of the code contained within your @media queries is an effective way to add dynamic style properties to your pages elements, while leaving your 'default' css intact for easy maintenance.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {

    /* CSS styles targeting screens of smaller sizes and/or resolutions (IE phones and tablets)  */

        #semantically-named-element p 
        { width: 60% !important;
        background: rgba(0,0,255,1)!important;
        margin: auto !important; }

        #semantically-named-element span 
        { display: none !important; }

    } 
    /* Look ma no media queries needed for default CSS below! Very easy to discern default styles, when the default code is the stuff not wrapped in queries. Period. */    

    /* Default CSS style attributes for any viewports that do not fit into the low or high resolution/screen size parameters set above and below. Also the fallback for browsers that still disregard CSS media queries */  
    #semantically-named-element p 
        { width: 90%;
          background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
          margin: auto; }

    #semantically-named-element span 
        { display: block;
          background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
          color: #FFF;
          text-align: center;}  
    @media all and (min-width: 968px) {
    /* CSS styles targeting very large or very high resolution viewports at the 769 pixels wide "break-point" */
        #semantically-named-element p 
        { width: 80% !important;
        background: rgba(0,255,0,1)!important;
        margin: auto !important; }

        #semantically-named-element span 
        { display: block !important;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)!important;
        color: #FFF !important; font-size: 200%; }
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="semantically-named-element">  
        <p> Usage of !important inside of the code contained within your @media queries is an effective way to add dynamic style properties to your pages elements, while leaving your 'default' css intact for easy maintenance.<span>hidden until tablet greater 768 viewport pixel width</span></p>
      </div>  
   </body>
</html>
```